# Core Graphic drew text outline with runtime not work in iOS10,iOS9 is ok

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, core-graphics, ios10

Core Graphic drew text outline with runtime does not work at iOS10. At iOS9 it works!

```
- (void)drawTextInRect_:(CGRect)rect {
  if ([self drawStroke]) {
    UIColor *textColor = self.textColor;
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, self.strokeSize);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(c, kCGLineJoinRound);

    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextStroke);
    self.textColor = self.strokeColor;
    [self drawTextInRect_:rect];

    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextFill);
    self.textColor = textColor;
  }
  [self drawTextInRect_:rect];
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? `[self drawTextInRect_:rect];` is again called from  this method, endless recursion.

Comment: use runtime replace uilabel's drawTextInRect:

Comment: Code readability is increased, tag is added